# Twilio API validate authorized number

Tags: twilio

I am unable to find a way to verify my Twilio number is correct before I use it as "from".  Does the API allow for validation of the number? I want to validate it before attempting the call which fails.

Comment: So is mostly for code questions and help.  You should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask for assistance in how to ask questions on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you want to use a number as the caller ID, you need to verify it in your Twilio console here: https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/verified.

Comment: I understand that, what I am looking for is an API to validate if the number my program is going to use to make the outbound calls is a verified number before I attempt to make calls using it.

Comment: Ah, in that case you want the [Outgoing Caller IDs resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/outgoing-caller-ids).